# Using Discord.net and C#, I want to embed a custom emote to a bot message

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am writing a discord bot using Discord.Net and C# and our server has many custom emotes in certain announcements. When I use this code, the emote never shows when the bot posts a message and I have tried a few different approaches with the only result being the message containing just plain text.

```
private Emote getEmote(string slashEmote = "<:338_patch:751808652834373673>")
        {
            Emote Emotion;
            if(Emote.TryParse(slashEmote, out Emotion))
            {
                return Emotion;
            }
            return Emotion;
        }

        [SlashCommand("emote", "Test function for custom emotes")]
        public async Task respondEmote()
        {
            var test1 = getEmote();
            if(test1 == null) { await RespondAsync("EMOTE NOT FOUND"); return; }
            string test = getEmote() + "**TEST** <:338_patch:751808652834373673>";
            await RespondAsync(test);
        }
```

Result:
[image: result of using above code]

I have tried using the escape operator, ID, ToString(), and name of the emote but none of them resulted in the actual emote showing up in the message.

Comment: Have you tried sending `:338_patch:`?

Comment: Yes, It has the same outcome where it just outputs :338_patch: instead of the emote. if i post :338_patch: or the <:emote-name:emote-id> myself it works but the bot can't. The bot is able to post default emojis though.

Comment: Maybe the id is wrong? try sending `\:338_patch:` manually on the discord server and see if the result matches your string.

Comment: This is the result:        <:338_patch:751808652834373673>
It matches my string: <:338_patch:751808652834373673>

Answer (score 1):

OK, well I learned that emotes either don't transfer over when using a template for server creation or the template i used was older than the emotes in question.

For those that find this thread later, MAKE SURE YOUR EMOTES ARE ACTUALLY ON THE SERVER YOU HAVE THE BOT ON. Just because you can use it doesn't mean the bot can.

Comment: Please avoid capital letters for emphasizing. You may use **bold** for that.